# Drupal 7 Views related query

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Page and a Block both are created using Views.

I want to display this Block along with the Page i.e. on Left hand side, Page's content will be shown and on the Right hand side this block's content but at the same time I don't want to configure this block from the administrative settings. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 'page' template file for your view and use module_invoke() function to call your block into it.

Page template can use following pattern -

```
page--[path].html.twig
```

module_invoke() documentation -

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke/7